# Display one or more existing reports created in SSRS in a C# Visual Studios project no report server?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2008

I need to deploy one or more existing reports created in SSRS from a C# Visual Studios project without using a report server? The project we are working on only needs 3 reports and the project lead feels that establishing a report server is not justified.

We are working with Visual Studio 2010 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to generate your reports without the report server ?

If so, your best (but not recommander option) is to convert rdl files (your reports) to rdlc files (client reporting) and use them with the ReportViewer control (WebForms/WinForms). Depending in your implementation, it can be quite difficultt to do.

Here is a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: msdn has no examples for VS 2010 only 2005 and 2012

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 was released much earlier than SQL Server 2008, so ReportViewer 2008 is based on the 2005 version of RDL. 
A SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 server report is based on the 2008 version of RDL, so, it can't be degrade to 2005 RDLC.